# FreeBSD and R mongolite package installation error: missing openssl.pc file

Tags: freebsd, openssl, r

I am having problem with `mongolite` R package installation on FreeBSD. It seems that it is due to the fact that FreeBSD does not store `openssl.pc` file whatsoever. So my question is how to deal with this issue in order to install the `mongolite` package?

I installed `openssl` via its official FreeBSD port:

```
cd /usr/ports/security/openssl && make install config-recursive distclean
```

However, as I said, `openssl.pc` file can not be found anywhere in the system.

In case it matters, I am working within a jail.

---

### EDIT.

It seems that `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is defined and points to the directory where `openssl.pc` is indeed present.

```
pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
# results
/usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig:/usr/libdata/pkgconfig
```

And there is a file `/usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/openssl.pc`. Hence, it seems like everything was on its place, but apparently something is still wrong and I can not figure out what it is exactly.

---

Below is the full installation log:

```
* installing *source* package ‘mongolite’ ...
** package ‘mongolite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include 
Using PKG_LIBS=-lsasl2 -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto 
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl/sasl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev, libsasl2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel, cyrus-sasl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev, sasl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘mongolite’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/library/mongolite’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpJosV0D/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("mongolite") :
  installation of package ‘mongolite’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Did you add openssl as the default version from ports in make.conf?

Comment: Sorry, but I am a total newbie to FreeBSD and I do not understand what do you mean exactly by adding openssl as the default version from ports in make.conf?

Comment: `mongolite` seems to want `sasl` in addition to `openssl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use openssl from ports, you need to make sure all your builds are told to use it. The way to do that is enter, in /etc/make.conf, `DEFAULT_VERSIONS+=ssl=openssl` Then all your builds will use openssl from ports. You will need to rebuild mongolite.

Comment: Yes, thanks this helps. However, also sasl was missing, so only after adding it the problem was resolved.